# IO standard for RGMII interface of ethernet

Tags: ethernet, rgmii

I'm learning about the RGMII interface of ethernet. Can anybody please tell me What IO standard does the TX and RX line of RGMII interface support? Please help. I'm just a beginner

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Media-independent_interface#Signal_levels

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The two RGMII reference designs I have are both 2.5V LVCMOS. You should check the datasheet of the PHY chip you're using to confirm.

Answer (score 1):

Depends on RGMII version, but either 2.5V CMOS or 1.5V HSTL